# Entity Framework Multiple identity columns specified for table. Only one identity column per table is allowed

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a entity code first model with entities `Students` and `Courses` with many-to-many relationship. Here are my entities:

Course:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public Course()
    {
        Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }
}
```

Student:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Courses = new HashSet<Course>();
    }
}
```

And here is my DbContext:

```
public class UniversitySystemContext : DbContext
{
    public UniversitySystemContext() 
        : base("UniversityDb")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Students)
            .WithMany(p => p.Courses).
        Map(
            m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("CoursesId");
                m.MapRightKey("StudentId");
                m.ToTable("StudentCourses");
            });
    }
}
```

When I try to insert a new Course I get this: "Multiple identity columns specified for table 'Courses'. Only one identity column per table is allowed."

So what am I missing and how can it be fixed ?

Comment: It should be `CourseId` (without the "s") in the mapping.

Comment: with your code, following instructions `ctx.Courses.Add(new Course { Name = "test" }); ctx.SaveChanges();` run without exception.